# Get Video Duration jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, time, duration

I have a question. I am trying to get the duration of a source.

I want to do the next: When the page load i need to get the duration of the source but the problem is that when i want to get the duration apparently is not visible, only i can get the duration when i press a button. I need to know the duration since the start because i need to calculate a position on video/audio and send through currentTime.

> I try to do "alert" but the result is "NaN".

This is my code actually:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var asset = $('#asset')[0]; // Obtiene el Objeto
    var tipo = $('#asset').attr('class'); // Video, Audio, PDF
    var duracion = asset.duration;
    var porcentaje = $('#porcentaje').attr('data-percent'); 
    var tiempo = (porcentaje*duracion)/100;
    asset.currentTime = tiempo;
    alert(duracion); // NaN

    $("#guardar").click(function() {
        var avance = asset.currentTime;
        if(tipo == 'video' || tipo == 'audio'){
            porcentaje = parseInt((avance*100)/duracion);
        }
        else if(tipo == 'pdf'){
            porcentaje = 100;
        }
        alert(porcentaje);
    });
});
```

That's all. Thank you.

Gustavo G.

Comment: `avance` and `duracion` are strings - you can't do mathematical functions with strings - you'll get a `NaN` value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to wait at least until the metadata is loaded to get the videos duration, luckily there's an event for that

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var asset      = $('#asset')[0]; // Obtiene el Objeto
    var tipo       = $('#asset').attr('class'); // Video, Audio, PDF
    var duracion   = 0; 
    var tiempo     = 0;
    var porcentaje = $('#porcentaje').data('percent'); 

    asset.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function() {
        duracion = asset.duration;
        tiempo   = (porcentaje*duracion)/100;

        asset.currentTime = tiempo;
    });

    $("#guardar").click(function() {
        var avance = asset.currentTime;
        if(tipo == 'video' || tipo == 'audio'){
            porcentaje = parseInt((avance*100)/duracion);
        } else if(tipo == 'pdf') {
            porcentaje = 100;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you. I had more than one hour trying. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can directly invoke `onloadedmetadata` function for the same. It will call the duration of the video only when the metadata (video, images, etc) will completely loaded on the page and hence, prevent the code `NAN` in the output.
Example:

```
<video controls onloadedmetadata="function_name()" id="videoid">
  <source src="video_name.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

in JavaScript:

```
<script>
    function function_name() {
      var video_duration = document.getElementById('videoid').duration
      alert(video_duration); // or window.alert(video_duration); 
    }
</script>
```

In Jquery:

```
<script>
    function function_name() {
      var video_duration = $('#videoid').duration
      alert(video_duration); // or window.alert(video_duration); 
    }
</script>
```