# How to play .mov files in video tag

Tags: html, video, browser

I am trying to play .mov videos in HTML5 browser. I have tried everything available over the internet e.g.

- attribute "controls"
- using `<source>` tag
- using `src` attribute with even changing MIME type to mp4.

But Nothing worked for me. Can anyone suggest solution for this?

Comment: This should help you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12521849/how-to-embed-a-mov-file-in-html

Comment: Thanks for info Vadim but I have tried this also but it din help me

Answer (score 7):

The [Video tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video) only supports certain filetypes. The .MOV container uses the Quicktime codec which is proprietary Apple software and is not on the list of [Media formats supported by the HTML audio and video elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats). I'd suggest transcoding the footage to .MP4 and using that instead.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is converting the file to .mp4. There are several softwares you can use to do so. I suggest Handbrake.

https://handbrake.fr/

Answer (score 0):

For jQuery, try this code. What it does it get the data from the `input` tag and instantiates a `FileReader` instance. We add an event listener to this instance and we append a `<source>` tag as child to the `<video>` tag. We are able to get the duration once the data has been loaded. Adding a `type="video/mp4"` attribute to the source tag is a small enhancement that would work on most .mov files, but not all (untested). [This is an enhancement to another SO answer located here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34620231/2106309).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var data  = $('#file-input')[0]; // File from <input type="file"> tag
  var reader = new FileReader();

  reader.addEventListener('load', function() {
    var video = $('<video class="uploaded_video_src" controls></video>');

    if (reader.result) {
      $('.uploaded_video_src').append(`<source src="${reader.result}" type="video/mp4">`); // Add type attr for support for some .mov files

      video.on('loadedmetadata', function() {
        console.log('duration:', $(this)[0].duration);
      });
    }
  });
});
```